# Create project for Windows application in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureportal

I want to move my WPF application project from a private Azure Devops account to an organization account.

So I thought I'd just create a new project in the Azure portal and push my code to that project instead.

But when I start to configure a new project I can't select "Windows application" or anything similar to that, only web applications are available. And it want's to deploy to an Azure service which you can't deselect! So here is where I want to close the window and move to AWS.

I don't want to deploy my application or set up any servers. I just want to start a new organization project. A totally empty if nothing else!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the UI where it's prompting you to choose a "Windows application"?

Comment: I couldn't find it now. Maybe my memory serves me wrong. But that's not the important part. I simply want to start an empty project without any infrastructure or anything. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Just go to your Azure DevOps account and click the "New Project" button.

Comment: But the problem is that there are no empty project template. Only Web projects that wants to spin up infrastructure for deployment. Which I don't want!

Comment: Go to your Azure DevOps portal, not the Azure portal. `https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganization`.

Comment: Yeah so that was the problem... It was a bit misleading that I could start (web) projects from the Azure Portal. But when I logged in to Azure Devops it was as I remebered it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your project within your Azure DevOps web portal, (`https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganization`), *not* the Azure portal.

There's a lot of terminology confusion because Azure DevOps was/is an independent Microsoft service called "Visual Studio Team Services" up until recently. It's been brought under the Azure umbrella and rebranded, but an Azure DevOps account has its own totally separate interface, which is where you should do most day-to-day operations.